# Get and Set data from user on a Custom Profile Provider in Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've been reading some tutorials and I have created the following class so that i can get user data and store it and access it anytime in the application when authenticated

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;

namespace FolhaRegisto.Models
{
    public class CustomProfileProvider : ProfileProvider
    {

        public override int DeleteInactiveProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override int DeleteProfiles(string[] usernames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override int DeleteProfiles(ProfileInfoCollection profiles)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override ProfileInfoCollection FindInactiveProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, string usernameToMatch, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override ProfileInfoCollection FindProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override ProfileInfoCollection GetAllInactiveProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override ProfileInfoCollection GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override int GetNumberOfInactiveProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption authenticationOption, DateTime userInactiveSinceDate)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        public override SettingsPropertyValueCollection GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection collection)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override void SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the DataBase, I want to set and get in the ProfileProvider Email so I can access it whenever I want when user is authenticated.

```
CREATE TABLE hUtilizadores
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Username NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    Password NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Acesso NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE hColaboradores
(
    IdUser INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Nome NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)


ALTER TABLE hColaboradores
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_hColaboradores_hUtilizadores 
FOREIGN KEY (IdUser) 
REFERENCES hUtilizadores(Id)
```

In web config I have this

```
  <profile>
  <providers>
    <add
      name="CustomProfileProvider"
      type="FolhaRegisto.Models.CustomProfileProvider" 
      connectionStringName="GestaoRequisicoes" /> 
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Because information is verly limited about Custom Profile Provider for Web Forms, I couldn't find any explicit example showing how to get data and store on Profile and where to make the Database Call I don't know which functions i have to implement and where I get the data from database